# Patrón Modelo-Vista-Controlador

Tags: web

Me gustaría saber en que influye el patrón MCV a la hora de codificar una
aplicación web. Estoy estudiando y entiendo las partes que tiene, a que se
encarga la parte de la vista, del negocio etc. Y su finalidad, separar
la logica de la presentación... Me gustaría que me ilustrarais con un ejemplo
practico a que se dedica cada parte y en que nos afecta, a la hora de codificar, solo es para estructurar el codigo... Ya que yo hasta ahora, para hacer una aplicación en Php, pues la hago separando el css, el html y el php, el JavaScript... pero sin seguir nada.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Este foro es para responder problemas de codigo , me parece que tu pregunta no deberia ir aqui ,

Comment: Ah no lo sabia...

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -1):

Creo que te refieres al patron Modelo-Vista-Controlador.
Podrias revisar algo de informacion del framework symfony, te dejo un link donde muestra de una manera muy explicativa como funciona.

http://librosweb.es/libro/symfony_1_2/capitulo_2/el_patron_mvc.html